# MIPS Assembly - Convert letter case and print issue

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to write a program in MIPS assembly that reverses the letter case of a given string. I think I have successfully converted the string in the code below but it won't print. I think I converted it because when I run it one instruction at a time it goes through the correct loops the right amount of times. Any help on understanding how to print the new string would be greatly appreciated. The code I have written already is below, along with the error message I'm receiving. Thanks so much everyone!

```
.data

testString: .asciiz "TEST"
revString: .space 32
errorMessage: .asciiz "error, try again"

.text

la $t4, revString
la $t0, testString

checkCase:
    lb $t1, ($t0) #assigns char of string to $t1
    beqz $t1, end #ends loop
    li $t2, 'a'
    li $t3, 'A'
    bge $t1, $t2, toUpper #confirms lowercase letter
    bge $t1, $t3, toLower #confirms uppercase letter
    j error #jumps to error if not a valid letter

toLower:
    addi $t1, $t1, 32 #converts upper to lowercase
    sb $t1, ($t4) #stores letter in $t4
    j continue #iterates both $t0 and $t4

toUpper:
    sub $t1, $t1, 32 #converts lower to uppercase
    sb $t1, ($t4) #stores letter in $t4
    j continue #iterates both $t0 and $t4

continue: #jumps to next letter in testString and revString
    add $t0, $t0, 1
    add $t4, $t4, 1
    j checkCase

error:
    la $a0, errorMessage #prints error message
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

end: #prints reversed letter case string
    #move $t4, revStr #assigns string in $t4 to revStr
    la $a0, ($t4)
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
```

Trying to print $t4 doesn't work and if I try to make revStr equal $t4's value, I get this error message:

```
line 42 column 12: "revStr": operand is of incorrect type
```

Comment: Why don't you search in your source for "revStr" definition first? (there isn't any ... because you named it differently). BTW *"I run it one instruction at a time it goes through the correct loops the right amount of times"* .. that's doesn't mean that much, usually it's good also to have an eye on register values, if it goes as expected. And finally your error is compile-time, so no need to debug at all, with compiler error you have to focus on syntax first (like using wrong label name or typo in some letter).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I didn't notice that typo. I fixed it but am still getting the same error. I'll try going through again looking at the register values. I think I might not fully understand move. I'll post an update when I test a little further. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to display the content of revStr (`revString`) buffer, right? So you need to load `$a0` with the buffer address, but that's exactly what symbol `revString` is, it's address of that space (not a "variable" as in higher language). so `la $a0, revString` `li $v0, 4` `syscall` will probably work. But try to re-read some stuff about addresses/memory/etc, to see if it will make more sense now after this initial experience. Also the first typo problem.. when programming, never believe you have in the source what you intended. Whenever debugging, try to re-read it with "fresh eyes".

Comment: except you will maybe hit yet one more bug if that string is displayed... It would be perfect opportunity to exercise your debugger "view memory" capabilities (focus on memory part containing those strings to understand how they are stored), to see how the memory looks at `end:`. But maybe that bug will not show with some luck, so change `revString: .space 32` to `revString: .byte 33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33` (which is similar to `.space 16` with initialized values) to see the bug.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I'll definitely be doing some rereading and the fresh eyes idea is really good because I often find that happens to me when I walk away from my code and return to it. Thanks again! I'll update revString too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(summary of answers from comments:)

Initial problem was typo in symbol name (`revStr` instead of `revString`), and using wrong instructions to load address of buffer to print the result, which should have looked like this:

```
end: #prints reversed letter case string
    la $a0, revString  # assign memory address of result string
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
```

---

After those fixes there's still at least one bug in the code, which will become visible after replacing `revString: .space 32` with:

```
    # 16 bytes space initialized to 33
revString: .byte 33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33
```

(fix is quite obvious, once you understand how `asciiz` strings are stored in memory, and how the memory looks at `end:` label, just check in debugger).

---

And some advanced hints:

Back in era of early CPUs the performance of code was very important, thus before writing any instructions programmer spent usually considerable time thinking what he really want to achieve and what are the options to do that.

In your case you want to turn 'A' (and similar) into 'a' and vice versa. 'A' is value 65 (ASCII definition), 'a' is value 97, so your +-32 is correct idea. But if you check the ASCII table even closely, and imagine the binary representation of values of upper/lower case letters, you will find out each letter value has the same bit pattern except the 5th bit (value 32). So instead of doing +-32 you can for letters just flip that bit by `xor $t1,$t1,32` without branching (or validate that the value is at least >= 'A').

Also in current code both branches have the same `sb $t1, ($t4)`, after writing first version look for such duplicities and refactor the code by moving those two writes at `continue:` label. If you look for re-usable code pieces often, and refactor them out, or turn groups of instructions into callable procedures, your code will have less duplicities, and overall will be quite shorter (for the prices of a tad more complex execution flow logic with additional calls). Shorter code = less debugging (usually, not guaranteed).